# React Router - Unexpected Redirect Behaviour with multiple redirect components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm coming across the following scenario:

I have a react router wrapped react component rendered  with 3 routes:

1. If the route matches "/about", redirect the user to "/about-new".
2. If a route is matched, display the associated component.
3. If the the route requested doesn't exist, redirect user to "/404".

[see live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-starter-forked-3nnc4?file=/src/index.js).

What I'm finding is that when I click on the link to navigate to "about" page, the route changes to /404 instead of "/about-new" and when I click on the link that goes to a non-existing route, it attempts to navigate to that route instead of "/404".

Is the expected behaviour for React Router? Is there something wrong with the way I defined my component? Or is this a bug with React Router?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a route for the `About` component.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-starter-forked-f715c?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I forgot to remove the About component. The intent is to redirect the user from '/about' to '/about-new' page instead of rendering a component.

Comment: By the `page` do you mean another page of the website? Not a part of React application?

Comment: The new about page is part of the react application. However, the goal is to use redirect to change the browser URL to the new URL to allow react-router to render the correct component at a higher level rather than having this component manage the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In my search for the answer, I realize the behaviour of `<Redirect>` is lacking documentation. I've played around with it a bit to understand how it works.

## Short Answer

Yes, this is the expected behaviour.

## Long Answer

When `<Redirect from='...' to='...'>` is matched, React Router will attempt to find a matching `<Route>` within your application. This could be a match from your local switch or from a parent switch in the case of a micro frontend application.

From the code base, my understanding is that a Router is always trying to find a component to render; After all, the nature of React is to translate JSX elements into JavaScript and spitting out plain HTML.

If no route is matched, the redirect will be ignored and continue down the switch. This is why in my example `<Redirect to='/404'>` was matched.

As you can [see from the code here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/modules/Redirect.js), the `<Redirect>` component's job is to replace browser history and since it isn't really rendering anything, the router continues its search for some component to render.

In the scenario where there is no `<Redirect>` with only routes, and no route has been matched, it will fall back to changing the browser URL to what is stated in `to={...}` argument of the Redirect and display a blank page.

So the behaviour for React Router within a `<Switch>` is that routing only stops when a `<Route>` is matched or when a blank page is displayed when no `<Route>` is matched.